# Highcharts How to get decimal point values on y-axis with big numbers

Tags: highcharts

I am graphing weather data in highcharts. I have some pressure data in hectopascals (hpa) and millibars (mb), so the numbers are quite large, but in a small range. For example, I have 60 data points between 1011.7 hpa and 1012.2 hpa.

When I graph this data, the axis labels all come out to (1012; rounded).

Obviously, I am missing a setting which will force the chart to display the correct values in 0.25 increments. I've set `tickInterval` to `0.25`, but this does not change the y-axis labels.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 25):

You will need to set the [y-axis label format](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.format). For example:

```
$("#container").highcharts({
    // ...
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: '{value:.2f}'
        }
    }
});
```

More information on how the axis can be formatted [can be found in the formatting documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. A bit surprised I did not need it for small number.

Comment: No problem. If the answer solved your problem, you should accept it (e.g. click on the checkmark beside this answer).

Comment: First link is invalid.

Comment: Also - don't forget to specify `{value:.2f}` on your tooltips too, if you have them.

Comment: This doesn't force 2 decimal places if the number is a whole number